# Cannot start OpenVPN on sheevaplug. Any suggestions?

Tags: debian, openvpn, arm

I installed OpenVPN on my arm-based sheevaplug (OS is Debian 7 Wheezy, kernel 3.8.8.) but as soon as i try to start the service i receive the following error:

```
[....] Starting virtual private network daemon: serverSIOCSIFADDR: No such device
: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFDSTADDR: No such device
: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFMTU: No such device
 failed!
```

Also modeprobe tun outputs the following:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:554 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.8.8/modules.dep.bin'
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?
I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: And what do you have for your OpenVPN config?

Comment: I found the solution. I recently upgraded my kernel to 3.8.8 but i didn't upgrade the modules so it was using ver. 2.6.30.2. I downloaded the modules for this kernel and i unzipped the folder under /lib/modules/3.8.8. It works... Thanks anyway!

Comment: self-answer your question, and mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I have low reputation points so i can only answer my question after 7 hours from the initial question. I will do this asap.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I recently upgraded my kernel to 3.8.8 but i didn't upgrade the modules so it was using ver. 2.6.30.2. I downloaded the modules for this kernel and i unzipped the folder under /lib/modules/3.8.8. It works... Thanks anyway!